# Pandas: Group by Name and Take Row With Most Recent Date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns `A, B, C, D, date`.  I want to filter out duplicates of `A` and `B`, keeping the row with the most recent value in `date`.

So if I have two rows that look like:

```
A B C D date

1 1 2 3 1/1/18

1 1 2 3 1/1/17
```

The correct output would be:

```
A B C D date

1 1 2 3 1/1/18
```

I can do this by looping through, but I'd like to use `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])` and then aggregate by taking the largest value for `date` in each group.

I tried:

`df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(lambda x: x.iloc[x.date.argmax()])`

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Edit: Hmm if I do:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).UPDATED_AT.max()
```

I get mostly what I want but I lose columns `D` and `C`...

Answer (score 7):

You can do with

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates(['A','B'],keep='last')
   A  B  C  D       date
0  1  1  2  3 2018-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(lambda x: x.iloc[x['date'].argmax()])`
pandas has its own date object. Maybe pandas got confused with the series name.

Comment: Interesting idea but just changed the column to `updated_at` and same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 2, 3, '1/1/18'],
                    [1, 1, 2, 3, '1/1/17']], 
                    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'date'])
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   date
0   1   1   2   3   1/1/18
1   1   1   2   3   1/1/17
```

Grouping an
d removing duplicate:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(
    {
        'date': 'max'
    })
```

Output:

```
        date
A   B   
1   1   1/1/18
```

This should work. It may work better with having 'date' column to be datetime object.